# My custom header component goes out of the screen in react native

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

In my react native application I have set up a custom header component like this.

```
const ChatHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.chatHederCiontainer}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={require('_assets/img/doctor1.png')}
            style={styles.chatImage}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', marginLeft: 20}}>
          {/* {props.name ? (
            <View>
              <Apptext styles={styles.ChatTextName}>{props.name}</Apptext>

              <Apptext styles={styles.ChatTextStatus}>
                {props.isActive ? strings('chat.active') : null}
              </Apptext>
            </View>
          ) : ( */}
          <Apptext styles={styles.ChatText}>
            Chat with Doctor and tell your problem
          </Apptext>
          {/* )} */}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    name: state.feedbacks.chatperson,
    isActive: state.feedbacks.active,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChatHeader);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  chatHederCiontainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  chatImageConatiner: {
    width: '20%',
  },
  ChatTextContainer: {
    width: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  chatImage: {
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
  },
  ChatText: {
    fontSize: normalize(15),
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  ChatTextName: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: normalize(12),
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  ChatTextStatus: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: normalize(9),
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
});
```

This is how I have used that in my navigations.

```
<ChatStack.Screen
      name="chat"
      component={ChatScreen}
      options={(props) => ({
        headerShown: true,
        headerLeft: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="tab"
            hitSlop={{top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 50, right: 50}}
            onPress={() => {
              global.currentScreenIndex = 1;
              props.navigation.goBack();
            }}>
            <Icon
              name="chevron-left"
              size={normalize(15)}
              color="#aaaaaa"
              style={{marginLeft: 20}}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerTitle: () => <HeaderTitle />,
        // headerTitleAlign: 'left',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
          height: 90,
        },
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerLeftContainerStyle: {},
        headerStatusBarHeight: 0,
      })}
    />
```

But when I run in the device it goes out of the device like this.

[image]

I tried a lot of things like changing styles but the issue is still the same can someone help me out with this. Thank you very much

Comment: What means goes out of the device ? Is it goes on the statusbar ?

Comment: @KishanBharda as you can see in the screenshot I have provided. It is hiding half of the text. only it is showing Chat with doctor and tel but the text is Chat with Doctor and tell your problem

Answer (score 1):

Add props headerMode={'none'} to <ChatStack.Screen> tag. Hope help U